Component missing after installing million.js on my React App
Increment and Decrement Component missing
i added the million to my project and suddenly the increment and decrement button is missing, if i remove the million in my config and set it to default the button will appear again
vite.config.js
import million from "million/compiler";
import MillionLint from "@million/lint";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
const _plugins = [react()];
_plugins.unshift(
  million.vite({
    auto: true,
  }),
  MillionLint.vite()
);
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: _plugins,
});


here's my Counter.jsx
...prev code

  return (
    <section className="counter">
      <p className="counter-info">
        The initial counter value was <strong>{initialCount}</strong>. It{" "}
        <strong>is {initialCountIsPrime ? "a" : "not a"}</strong> prime number.
      </p>
      <p>
        <IconButton icon={MinusIcon} onClick={handleDecrement}>
          Decrement
        </IconButton>
        <CounterOutput value={currentCounter} />
        <IconButton icon={PlusIcon} onClick={handleIncrement}>
          Increment
        </IconButton>
      </p>
      <CounterHistory history={counterChanges} />
    </section>
  );
});

export default Counter;


Expected Result

Nice. I have faced same issue by passing react course. Did you find a solution?

Upd: I only found the component is not shown when children are passed. Without children it works. No clue why.
